# How GDI+ DrawString draws the string with hieroglyphs when Font doesn't support these symbols

Tags: fonts, gdi+

How it's possible that the GDI+ DrawString() method can draw a string with hieroglyphs characters, even if the Font selected for it doesn't support these symbols?

```
FontFamily  fontFamily("Segoe UI");
Font font(&fontFamily, 16, FontStyleRegular, UnitPoint);

SolidBrush brush(Color::Black);
graphics.DrawString("测试", -1, &font, PointF(10,10), &brush);
```

but system says Segoe UI can not draw it.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DrawString incorporates a font fallback mechanism: it detects that the selected font does not support characters being displayed and so selects different system fonts for displaying each of those characters.

Most text frameworks, especially those designed to be easy to use for displaying UI strings, will all have some font fallback logic. This includes GDI ExtTextOut, User32 DrawText, DirectWrite IDWriteTextLayout, XAML text controls, browser layout engines, etc. There are also lower-level text APIs that allow the developer to control more of the functionality and that don't do any font fallback (which is why in the Settings UI in your screenshot no font fallback is done).

Comment: Thank you! It would be nice if you give links on documentation about it. Most interesting is lower-level text rendering control.

Comment: I don't think there's much I can point to for GDI+. But I can provide some pointers for GDI and DirectWrite.

Comment: GDI uses the Uniscribe component for complex script layout, and one of the Uniscribe capabilities is font fallback. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-font-fallback. For lower-level operation, you can tell GDI not to call into Uniscribe by specifying ETO_IGNORELANGUAGE in the ExtTextOut call. You can also use ETO_GLYPH_INDEX to pass in specific glyph IDs rather than characters, in which case it will not call into Uniscribe. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-exttextoutw for those options.

Comment: Even when ETO_IGNORELANGUAGE is specified, you might still get some font fallback behaviour that's built into GDI directly. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/input/font-technology#font-linking.

Comment: For more control, Uniscribe APIs can be called directly to do layout, then calling ETO with ETO_GLYPH_INDEX for drawing. Uniscribe has higher-level and lower-level APIs: The ScriptString* functions are higher-level, and are what ETO calls into. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-the-scriptstring-functions. For lower-level operation, other functions such as ScriptItemize, ScriptShape and ScriptPlace would be use. There's a bunch of Uniscribe documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/uniscribe.

Comment: Back in the 2000s and even more recently, MS apps such as Word and IE or the RichEdit control would make use of the lower-level Uniscribe APIs (along with ETO + ETO_GLYPH_INDEX) in many situations, perhaps by-passing Uniscribe if the text didn't require complex script shaping. But Word, IE and RichEdit would apply their own font fallback logic, so GDI font linking and Uniscribe font fallback would not be used.

Comment: Btw, in Uniscribe, the font fallback logic is applied in the ScriptStringAnalyze function, and can be enabled or disabled by the SSA_FALLBACK flag. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/usp10/nf-usp10-scriptstringanalyse.

Comment: In WPF, font fallback is handled using the FontFamilyMap class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.fontfamilymap?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). Each map specifies a specific font family to use for particular Unicode character ranges. The map can also be tailored by language. Then, a composite "font family" can be created by constructing a FontFamily object then setting one or more font family maps. WPF has a default set of mappings defined in a set of .compositefont files (XML). You can create .compositefont files for your app to define custom font fallback.

Comment: For more on WPF font fallback, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.fontfamily?view=windowsdesktop-6.0.

Comment: In DirectWrite, the IDWriteTextLayout interface (and numbered variants) is the key interface specific to higher-level operation. An IDWriteTextFormat is first created and then passed when IDWriteFactory::CreateTextLayout is called. IDWriteTextLayout will do font fallback, complex script shaping, bidi and line breaking to lay out a paragraph of text. Lower-level operation would be done using IDWriteTextAnalyzer to handle bidi, line breaking, shaping (::GetGlyphs) and placement of glyphs (::GetGlyphPlacements). For lower-level operation, an app can provide its own font fallback logic.

Comment: DirectWrite documentation is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/direct-write-portal.

Comment: For controlling font fallback in DWrite, the IDWriteFontFallbackBuilder interface is used. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_2/nn-dwrite_2-idwritefontfallbackbuilder. Conceptually, font fallback in DWrite is just like font family maps in WPF. Each mapping specifies a family name (or priority list of family names) for one or more Unicode character ranges, and the mappings can be tailored by language.

Comment: After one or mappings is added to the builder, the IDWriteFontFallback object is created, and then it can be set on a text format or text layout object (IDWriteTextFormat1::SetFontFallback, IDWriteTextLayout2::SetFontFallback).

Comment: Btw, in WPF, a FontFamilyMap can take a family priority list, just as in DWrite. With a priority list, if the selected font doesn't support a given character, the platform will try each font family in the priority list, in order, stopping at the first that supports the given character. Conceptually, this is all very much like how font-family and @font-face work in CSS.